# How to get entry from datastore by position it was added? (Google app engine and JDO)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

Here is my example:
Add new entry to datastore //position 1
Add new entry to datastore //position 2
Add new entry to datastore //position 3

Now i want to get entry, that was added at position 2. How it can be done with google app engine and JDO?

Looks for me that one way is to give PrimaryKey as Long ID and then use getObjectById. So Long ID will be equal to storing position automatically by the datastore.
Code that shows it:

```
import javax.jdo.annotations.*;
import javax.jdo.PersistenceManager;
import mypackage.PMF

public class Entry {
  @PrimaryKey
  @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
  private Long ID;

  //.. other fields
}


// create entries (suppose datastore is empty and i don't need deletes in future)
PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager()
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
  pm.makePersistent(new Entry());
}
// created entries have their IDs exaclty = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 ?

// fetch entry, that was added second
Key entryKey = KeyFactory.createKey(Entry.class.getSimpleName(), 2L);
Entry secondEntry = pm.getObjectById(Entry.class, entryKey);
```

Can i be sure that Long ID field will be always incremented by 1 for new entry and it will equal 1 for first?
Or there is another better way? :)

Comment: "Position 2" based on what exactly ? you have to have some property that you're basing it on.

Comment: if you mean ID, which is not what you said, then you simply do a JDOQL query and order by id, and pick the second item

Comment: "Position 2" is index of element secondly added (it was second element, that was added to database). Like List in java: myArrayList.add(new Entry);  myArrayList.add(new Entry);  myArrayList.add(new Entry);. Now i cat get second element: secondEntry = myArrayList.get(1). I want the same behaviour in datastore

Comment: Yes, query you told about can return the needed entry. But isn't it too big operation for fetching only one element? The query will return all entries... Well, if the idea with primary key as index is not good, i'll have to use query :)

Comment: the query returns what range you want. suggest you read up on jdoql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This notion of "position" isn't an App Engine concept. App Engine makes no guarantee that system-generated IDs will be assigned sequentially with no gaps.

See http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities.html#Kinds_IDs_and_Names

You can take over ID assignment yourself, if you're careful, but, depending on your app and its usage pattern, creating your own ids introduces a bottleneck that'll limit your ability to create new entities quickly.

Comment: Looks like better solution for my problem is to use queries... Thanks!